# How can we create a relationship, but disallow updating one of the tables? and difference between insertWithRelated vs. upsertGraph

Tags: knex.js, objection.js

I am just learning objectionJS in NodeJS Javascript application, but i am confused about one thing.

I have two questions:

1. If I have a table called "Groups" and I am inserting "Users" in a ManyToMany style (and a link table groups_users).  How do we generate a query such that it allows insertion of a user, and create a relationship with group, but forbid editing the group.  This would prevent inadvertently editing the group table via the client.   I tried insertWithRelated, and upsertGraph.  I tried allowInsert, but it says "no permissions" or it inserts and updates the groups table. Also how would we do this in a HasMany relationship.
2. Can someone please explain why I would use insertWithRelated vs. upsertGraph (or insertGraph).  My object coming back example:
   Users {username: **_, password: _**, groups: [{id: 22, groupName: 'myGroup'}]}.  I wonder if I use insertWithRelated, do I have to manually insert into the link table?  is that the difference?

Thank you very much in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Validate that group is not changed before query or limiting what can be upserted with `allowUpsert` https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/api/query-builder/mutate-methods.html#allowupsert
2. https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/api/query-builder/mutate-methods.html#insertwithrelated there is no difference at all between insertWithRelated and insertGraph. Upsert graph in the other hand is much more complicated and powerful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!